# Python Import Error, Symbol not found: _iconv Referenced from:

Tags: python, macos, opencv, cgi

I've successfully running **Python 2.7.15** (default one) on **macOS Sierra 10.12.6.**

I have also installed OpenCV using pip of version 3.4.0, using [this](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) tutorial.

*Screenshot:* [Python IDLE Screenshot showing OpenCV version on macOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkdI0.png)

When I try to import cv2 from python IDLE it gets successfully imported, but when I try import cv2 from a python script and run as cgi script, it shows the following error:

**Error Screenshot:** [OpenCV import error while importing and running from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D8P4.png)

1. What does the error actually mean?
2. How can I solve this?

*Note: I've no errors while running python as CGI scripts (without importing opencv).*

> **Note:** I've even tried of installing OpenCV using Homebrew but it still produces the same error while importing OpenCV as a CGI script.

Comment: you probably run the script with another python installation... make sure you are installing opencv with the pip to the same python you use in the second case.... the one in "Library/Frameworks/Python.Frameworks......"

Comment: @api55 It's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very common error with OpenCV, the best move you can do is to install OpenCV using Anaconda.

I recommend you to fully uninstall Python and install Anaconda Python, it comes with the `conda` package manager that will allow you to install opencv--python easily.

https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Once Anaconda Python is installed, try the following commands:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv

conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

Comment: Just curious, Isn't there a other way around, like without installing Anaconda Python? And if I install opencv and python using Anaconda will python script run as CGI script(s) ? :) @jonathan-dekhtiar

Comment: There are ways. But it is really complicated. Check on google this has been answered countless times.